# Changing text of customer "edit address" field

Tags: template, magento-1, localisation

Please see this image:

[image]

I would like to change the "Middle Name/Initials" text to just "M.I." because it currently ruins the formatting. Where is the file located in order to change this?

Also, if it's a core file, will I need to edit it with each update of Magento?

Answer (score 4):

> **Never edit core files in Magento!**

### Solution without changing core files

You can define custom translations in your theme, create the following file if it does not exist yet:

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

(replace `en_US` if you use a different language)

Note that this should be a project specific theme, not `rwd/default` or `some_bought_theme/default`. If you did not already, you can add a child theme next to `default` and specify this one as theme in the system configuration. You don't need to copy anything from the `default` directory since Magento falls back automatically, so you only need to add the files that are customized.

In the `translate.csv` you can add your custom translations. Since the translated string is "Middle Name/Initial" and it's coming from the `Mage_Customer` module, you need to add this line:

```
"Mage_Customer::Middle Name/Initial","M.I."
```